# Fill missing values in 2D array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2D array with the values day and total:

```
val:[['02', 14487.97 ],
    [ '03', 28230.21 ],
    [ '05', 58017.5 ],
    [ '08', 79214.96 ]]
```

I need to fill the days that are missing with the value of the last day. Example:

```
 final: [[ '02', 14487.97 ],
        [ '03', 28230.21 ],
        [ '04', 28230.21 ],
        [ '05', 58017.5 ],
        [ '06', 58017.5 ],
        [ '07', 58017.5 ],
        [ '08', 79214.96 ],
```

--Edited
I did the code below, but not sure if it's optimzed.

```js
arr  =[['02', 14487.97 ],
    [ '03', 28230.21 ],
    [ '05', 58017.5 ],
    [ '08', 79214.96 ]]

function zeroPad(num, places) {
  var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
  return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
}

init=parseInt(arr[0][0])
end=parseInt(arr[arr.length-1][0])
for (var i=init; i<end; i++) {
    try {
        if(arr[i]) {
            if (arr[i][0] != zeroPad(i+1, 2)) {
                var item = [zeroPad(i+1, 2), arr[i-1][1]];
                arr.splice(i, 0, item);
            }
        }
        else {
            var item = [zeroPad(i+1, 2), arr[i-1][1]];
            arr.splice(i, 0, item);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
        console.log(e);
        break;
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Best regards

Comment: What have you tried, and what's the specific issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducers can be useful for this kind of thing. This works, and doesn't change the original array (ES5 syntax):

```js
var val = [
  ["02", 14487.97],
  ["03", 28230.21],
  ["05", 58017.5],
  ["08", 79214.96]
];

// zeroPad function borrowed from Stack Overflow somewhere...
function zeroPad (size, num){
  var s = num + "";
  while (s.length < size) {s = "0" + s;}
  return s;
};

function fillMissingRows (acc, row){
  function num (r){return parseInt(r[0]);}
  var prev = acc[acc.length - 1] || [];
  for (var i = 1; i < num(row) - num(prev); i++) {
    acc.push([zeroPad(2, num(prev) + i), prev[1]]);
  }
  acc.push(row);
  return acc;
};

console.log(val.reduce(fillMissingRows,[]));
/* 
[
  [ '02', 14487.97 ],
  [ '03', 28230.21 ],
  [ '04', 28230.21 ],
  [ '05', 58017.5 ],
  [ '06', 58017.5 ],
  [ '07', 58017.5 ],
  [ '08', 79214.96 ]
]
*/
```

The reducing function `fillMissingRows` takes each row of the val array in turn and checks if there's a gap between the index number of the previous row of the array and the current row. If there is, it inserts the appropriate number of copies of the previous row, with its index number increased and zero-padded, into its result (`acc`), before inserting the current row as well and moving on to the next row.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce for details of reduce.

Answer (score 0):

I did this version just with loops without losing the original array:

```
var data = [['02', 14487.97 ],
    [ '03', 28230.21 ],
    [ '05', 58017.5 ],
    [ '08', 79214.96 ]];

function fillMissedRows(data){
    var arr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= data.length-1; i++){
        arr.push(data[i]);
        if(i < data.length-1){
            if(Math.abs(data[i][0] - data[(i+1)%data.length][0]) > 1){
                for(let j = parseInt(data[i][0], 10)+1; j < parseInt(data[(i+1)%data.length][0], 10); j++){
                    var res = [(j+"").length > 1 ? j+"" : "0"+j, data[i][1]];
                    arr.push(res);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(fillMissedRows(data));
```